# load script in a page in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my angular application, there are some html templates loaded using directives and thoses templates contain scripts. I want to separate those scripts and load into that templates when templates are loaded. Can I do that using separate directives? Or is there any way to load script when loading those templates using directives?

Please suggest me

```
<div>
    <div class="rs-textarea">
        <textarea id="summernote" class="insertText"></textarea>
        <script>
            $('#summernote').summernote({
                focus: true,                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                height: 150,
                toolbar: [
                    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    // ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['insert', ['link', 'hr']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['view', ['codeview']],
                ]
            });
        </script>
        <div class="rb-option">
            <div class="option-icon ico-drag icon ion-arrow-move"></div>
            <div class="option-icon ico-settings icon ion-android-close DeleteSnippet"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Delete Snippet -->
        <script>
            $('.DeleteSnippet').on('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300);
            })
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of this, I want to have my text.html and text.js separately.
text.html>>

```
<div class="rs-textarea">
    <textarea id="summernote" class="insertText"></textarea>
    <div class="rb-option">
        <div class="option-icon ico-drag icon ion-arrow-move"></div>
        <div class="option-icon ico-settings icon ion-android-close DeleteSnippet"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

text.js>>

```
<script>
     $('#summernote').summernote({
           focus: true,
           height: 150,
           toolbar: [
               ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
               ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
               // ['fontname', ['fontname']],
               ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
               ['insert', ['link', 'hr']],
               ['table', ['table']],
               ['view', ['codeview']],
           ]
     });
</script>
<!-- Delete Snippet -->
<script>
    $('.DeleteSnippet').on('click', function () {
          $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300);
    })
</script>
```

Here is my directive that is loading text.html

```
.directive('drText', function (){
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                templateUrl: "app/webapp/templates/snippets/text.html",
                replace: true,
                   scope: {
                       list: "="

                   }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the `link` property is there for:

```
.directive('drText', function (){
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "app/webapp/templates/snippets/text.html",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                list: "="
            },
            link: function($scope, $element) {
                $element.find('textarea').summernote({...});
                // delete handlers etc.
            }
        }
    })
```

By the way: in case you intend to add multiple `<dr-text>` elements, you should not use the id attribute on the `<textarea>` as an id should be unique to a page.